# Vim regular expression for range of numbers - Not working

Tags: regex, vim

I have the following regular expression for range `288-303` but it is not working in GVim.
The regexp is `:/28[89]|29[0-9]|30[0-3]/`.

Could anyone please point out the reason. I referred Stack Overflow and got the regexp from http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range/42.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to escape the pipe in Vim:

```
:/28[89]\|29[0-9]\|30[0-3]/
```

**Edit:**

Per @Tim's comment, you can optionally prefix the pattern with `\v` instead of escaping the individual pipe characters:

```
:/\v28[89]|29[0-9]|30[0-3]/
```

Thanks @Tim.

Comment: Alternatively, can use the 'very magic' (`\v`) option: `/\v28[89]|29[0-9]|30[0-3]/`

Comment: OP's example started with `:`, and `\v` doesn't work there, but good point.  If you're just searching, `/\v` will work (in fact I have `/` remapped to `/\v`), but if you're doing the search from the command-line, you'll need to escape the pipes.  I've updated my answer to add the `:` from OP's example.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong about `:/\v`; I was testing it with the `\|` still in the regex.  You can use `\v` on the command-line too.  Nice tip!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jim answer I made a little script to search for integers in a given range. You use the command like :

```
:Range 341 752
```

This will match each sequence of digit between the two numbers 341 and 752.
Using a search like

```
/\%(3\%(\%(4\%([1-9]\)\)\|\%([5-9]\d\{1}\)\|\%(9\%([0-9]\)\)\)\)\|\%([4-7]\d\{2}\)\|\%(7\%(\%(0\%([0-9]\)\)\|\%([1-5]\d\{1}\)\|\%(5\%([0-2]\)\)\)\)
```

Just add that to your vimrc

```
function! RangeMatch(min,max) 
  let l:res = RangeSearchRec(a:min,a:max)
  execute "/" . l:res 
  let @/=l:res
endfunction  

"TODO if both number don't have same number of digit 
function! RangeSearchRec(min,max) " suppose number with the same number of digit 
if len(a:max) == 1 
  return '[' . a:min . '-' . a:max . ']'
endif 
if a:min[0] < a:max[0]  
  " on cherche de a:min jusqu'à 99999 x times puis de (a:min[0]+1)*10^x à a:max[0]*10^x
  let l:zeros=repeat('0',len(a:max)-1) " string (a:min[0]+1 +) 000000

  let l:res = '\%(' . a:min[0] .  '\%(' . RangeSearchRec( a:min[1:],   repeat('9',len(a:max)-1) ) . '\)\)' " 657 à 699

  if a:min[0] +1 < a:max[0]
    let l:res.= '\|' . '\%(' 
    let l:res.= '[' . (a:min[0]+1) . '-' .  a:max[0] . ']' 
    let l:res.= '\d\{' . (len(a:max)-1) .'}' . '\)' "700 a 900
  endif 

  let l:res.= '\|' . '\%(' . a:max[0] .  '\%(' . RangeSearchRec( repeat('0',len(a:max)-1) , a:max[1:] ) . '\)\)' " 900 a 957 

  return l:res
else 
  return  '\%(' . a:min[0] . RangeSearchRec(a:min[1:],a:max[1:]) . '\)' 
endif 
endfunction 
command! -nargs=* Range  call RangeMatch(<f-args>)
```

Note that the \%(\) matching parenthesis instead of \(\) avoid a ERROR E872: (NFA regexp) Too many '('

The script look between 341-399 or 400-699 or 700-752